# Integration tests with PHPUnit and Apache

Tags: php, apache, unit-testing, phpunit, integration-testing

In addition to unit testing with PHPUnit, I would like to do integration testing where my php test is loaded just like a php page would be with all Apache context available to the test (and the methods being tested).

In JUnit and Spring I would do this by using the [AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.html) class which would load the application context and make it available to the tests. I don't see a similar concept in the [PHPUnit documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/index.html).

If you aren't able to (or don't want to) mock everything necessary to test PHP code, is there a way to run PHPUnit tests through Apache?

As a concrete example, I want to test a method that calls X existing methods, many of which use the _SERVER array or other request-specific variables that I can't mock without a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I never try this, but it should work:

```
public function testSomeMethod()
{
    $_SERVER['some-var'] = 'some value';

    $x = $this->obj->getSomething();
    $this->assertEquals('expected', $x);
}
```

You can also backup $_SERVER variable and restore it later.

Comment: Right, but that's effectively mocking the _SERVER var. I'm working on an app with a LOT of values in _SERVER and I want them set to what they would be at runtime in Apache, not what I mock them to. If I was just unit testing mocking would be ok, I want integration testing.